# How to save an entity with a nested entity in Hibernate when both have id?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate3

We are using old Hibernate on our project (version 3.6.10), upgrade is not an option at this moment unfortunately.

I'm trying to save entities **with assigned ids** that have the following structure:

I have a `Base` class that contains `id` field. Please note `generator-class="assigned"`

```
public abstract class Base {

    private Long id;

    // contructor

    /**
     * @hibernate.id generator-class="assigned" unsaved-value="null"
     */
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    // setter
}
```

Then I have a class `Nested`

```
public class Nested extends Base {

    private Main main;

    // constructor

    /**
     * @hibernate.many-to-one column="main_id" not-null="true" fetch="join"
     * lazy="false" cascade="all"
     * class="Main"
     */
    public Main getMain() {
        return main;
    }
    
    // setter
}
```

And class `Main`:

```
public class Main extends Base {

    private List<Nested> nested;

    /**
     * @hibernate.bag cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true" batch-size="10" lazy="false"
     * @hibernate.key column="main_id" on-delete="cascade"
     * @hibernate.one-to-many class="Nested"
     */
    public List<Nested> getNested() {
        return nested;
    }
    // setter
}
```

When I construct Main object with a list of Nested object (all of them have ids) and try to save it (`getHibernateTemplate().save(main)`), I see in generated SQL queries:

`insert into main...`

and then

`update nested ...` I assume that's because nested records have ids already.

How can I make Hibernate insert records for `Nested` instances?

I know that I can save each entity separately, but I'd prefer to avoid that.

Comment: So is the issue that the updates are failing?  Because if they are succeeding then either you are updating existing entities, possibly on account of re-using IDs, or else the entities *are* being inserted at some point.

Comment: Also, to the best of my knowledge and ability to search documentation, the `unsaved-value` property is relevant only to *generated* IDs, not to assigned ones.  Hibernate does not rely on ID values to determine how to handle a cascading save for child entities with assigned IDs (except inasmuch as it must fail if such entities have not, in fact, been assigned an ID).

Comment: Hi John, thank you for you comments.

All entities should be inserted, not updated. I'm basically copying everything from one structure to another in db. That's why I know the ids already.

I've checked the logs and there is never an insert for Nested entity, it tries to update a record, which doesn't exist, so I get ```org.hibernate.StaleStateException```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to save each Nested entity separately, you could use a custom interceptor to modify the Hibernate behaviour for saving the entities.

Below is a sample implementation that could be used for the same

1. Implement a custom interceptor that extends org.hibernate.EmptyInterceptor

```
import org.hibernate.EmptyInterceptor;

public class CustomSaveInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

    @Override
    public boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
        if (entity instanceof Main) {
            Main main = (Main) entity;
            for (Nested nested : main.getNested()) {
                getSession().save(nested); // Manually save each nested entity
            }
        }
        return super.onSave(entity, id, state, propertyNames, types);
    }
}
```

2. Configure the custom interceptor in Hibernate configuration

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(
    new CustomSaveInterceptor()); // Pass your interceptor instance here
```

3. Use the configured SessionFactory to save your entities

```
Main main = new Main();
// Set properties for the Main object

Nested nested1 = new Nested();
// Set properties for the Nested object 1

Nested nested2 = new Nested();
// Set properties for the Nested object 2

main.getNested().add(nested1);
main.getNested().add(nested2);

sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(main); // Trigger saving with the interceptor
```

This approach involves intercepting saving process for Main entities using custom interceptor. When a Main entity is saved, the interceptor will manually save each associated Nested entity before proceeding with the normal process for Saving Main entity.

P.S.: This solution can affect the behaviour of the Hibernate session globally. As always, make sure to thoroughly test the change to make sure it works correctly for your specific use case.

Comment: Hi Pancham, thank you for suggested solution.

It still uses ```getSession().save(...)``` and for me it doesn't really matter where to call it (earlier in my method or in this interceptor)

I want to avoid that because in reality I have ~30 linked entities and I don't want to save them separately.

Comment: Did you tried using `cascade` attribute in the mapping annotations to control the behaviour during save and update operations.

1. In the Main class:
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "main", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST) // Use CascadeType.PERSIST
public List<Nested> getNested() {
    return nested;
}

2. In the Nested class: 
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST) // Use CascadeType.PERSIST
public Main getMain() {
    return main;
}

Comment: I did. Unfortunately it didn't work.